# Can we get an upper bound for $y(t)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $y: [0,T]\to R$ be a function. If $y$ satisfies the following inequality:
$$
y'(t)\le ay(t)+b
$$
for some constants $a, b>0$.

How to apply the Grönwall's inequality? Or can we get an upper bound for $y(t)$?

Comment: Just go apply the Gronwall's inequality. What's the problem here?

Comment: @NN2 I only see this version" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality... That is $y'\le ay$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\Longleftrightarrow \left(y(t) + \frac{b}{a}\right)' \le a \left(y(t) + \frac{b}{a}\right) $$
Applying the Gronwall's inequality for $z(t):=y(t) + \frac{b}{a}$, we have then
$$y(t) + \frac{b}{a} = z(t) \le z(0)e^{at}\Longrightarrow y(t) \le \left(y(0) +  \frac{b}{a}\right) e^{at} - \frac{b}{a}$$

Comment: How about this case $a, b\le 0$?

Comment: Also, how about if we generalize the condition $y(t)$ is negative?

Comment: @Hermi The result holds true whether $y(t)$ is negative or not

Comment: How about this case $y'(t)\le af(t)^2 y(t)+b$? Here $y(t): R\to [-2, \infty)$. So if we want to apply Gronwall's inequality, we need to get $af(t)^2 y(t)+b\le ay(t)+b$ but $y(t)$ could be negative... How to solve this problem?

Comment: I asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4560722/how-to-apply-apply-gr%c3%b6nwalls-inequality-for-yt-le-aft2-ytb

Comment: @Hermi You can still use Gronwall's inequality for this new problem. However, finding directly the upper bound is more cumbersome. I'll answer your new question .

Answer (score 1):

Apply the integrating factor $e^{-at}$ to get
$$
(e^{-at}y(t))'\le be^{-at}
$$
Now integrate, for instance over $[0,T]$. Remember that the integral is monotonous. One gets
$$
e^{-aT}y(T)-y(0)\le\frac{b}{a}(1-e^{-at}).
$$